# you are using a browser that is not supported by the google maps javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have .net windows web browser control, which loads the Google map

Recently it started to show "you are using a browser that is not supported by the google maps javascript api". I pin pointed that by default it is loaded on IE 7. Then I controlled it by adding

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Then made sure that it loads on IE 11 with the help of custom javascript function. But still it shows the message.
Note: This message is not appeared when map is loaded on stand alone browser with above tag.

Some one an idea why or what I should change? Control it by registry is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Remove directly with CSS.

```
  .infomsg {
      display:none;
    }
```

Comment: I did this workaround. But looking for proper solution :(.

Comment: Quite honestly I'm not sure if there is any other solution. This message is shown because you are using a browser not entirely compatible with the API. Since google wants you to use Chrome they probably won't be a good way of getting rid of the message.

Comment: Thanks for your comments